# File not uploaded on server using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I want to to bulk translocation and for that I uploaded the.csv file, its worked for me if I am using curl command but when I used its on node code its showing me error "file not uploaded"

Regarding to curl I am using that code  which is working for me :-

```
curl -F  'data=@/var/www/html/achupload.csv' https://sandbox.usaepay.com/api/v2/bulk_transactions  -H "Authorization: Basic X3llMVI3Mk9PdzFHOXBqcW1GaVp2NHJINjRc="
```

and this is my node code which are showing me error message :-

```
    var request = require('request');

    var headers = {
          'Authorization': 'Basic X3llMVI3Mk9PdzFHOXBqcW1GaVp2NHJINjRc='
    };

    var dataString = '@/var/www/html/achupload.csv';

    var options = {
        url: 'url',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        data: dataString
    };

    console.log("options====",options);

    function callback(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
        }
        else{
          console.log("notttttttttttt================",response.body);
        }
    }

    request(options, callback);
```

Comment: Because `dataString` is a string, not your `csv` file content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- File content is retrieved with `fs.createReadStream()`.
- The file is sent as `formData`.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var request = require('request');

var headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ###'
};

var dataString = '@/var/www/html/achupload.csv';

var options = {
    url: 'url',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    data: dataString
};
```

To:

```
var fs = require('fs');  // Added
var request = require('request');

var headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ###'
};

var dataString = {data: fs.createReadStream('/var/www/html/achupload.csv')};  // Modified

var options = {
    url: 'url',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    formData: dataString  // Modified
};
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, `'Authorization': 'Basic ###'` was used. Please be careful this. When you use this, please replace `###` to yours.

#### References:

- [fs.createReadStream()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options)
- [multipart/form-data (Multipart Form Uploads)](https://github.com/request/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads)

If this didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you so much,  you make my day :)

Comment: @Mangita  Welcome. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.